# Mpdf 6.1 - How to change font?

Tags: mpdf

I am using a Wordpress plugin that runs mpdf. I am using the plugin "ChordWP" and "ChordWP-Propack" but I run I to some struggles.

Could anyone help me with this error...?
How do I change the default font from “DejaVu Serif Condensed” to “DejaVu Sans Condensed” in mpdf 6.1?

The engraved pdf also give me one column and the plugin supposed to engrave two columns. Any suggestion?

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught MpdfException: mPDF Error - cannot find TTF TrueType font file - /public_html/.../mpdf60/ttfonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf 

mPDF->AddFont('dejavuserifcond...', '') 
#1 /public_html/.../mpdf60/mpdf.php(13621): mPDF->SetFont('dejavuserifcond...') 
#2 /public_html/.../mpdf60/mpdf.php(1287): mPDF->SetDefaultFont('serif')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly seems to be an error in the installation of the addon. Upload the Truetype font file to the fonts directory `/ttfonts..` or try it with python

```
pip install --user fonttools or pip3 install --user fonttools
```

code may appear something like this.

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont

font = TTFont('/path/to/font.ttf')
```

but it seems as if the file it self is missing

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, the file is missing and uploading "DejaVu Serif Condensed" solves the missing issue, this is why I want to change the default font from  "DejaVu Serif Condensed"  to “DejaVu Sans Condensed”.